# Why can't I see my events in Google Mobile Analytics? And another unique vists problem

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

I have two problems with google's mobile analytics: (I am using the native version - not web)

1. I see pagevies but I don't see my events. This might be since you can't configure the GA website to a native mobile app traching.
2. The app isn't launch yet, I am the only one using it and GA reports 14 **unique** visitors - ha?!

Answer (score 0):

1. Not exactly sure what you are asking, but can't really help without seeing code regardless
2. More than likely the GA cookie is being removed or not being set on your phone, or your IP address is changing or both.

Comment: I can see the views. I don't see events. I am not even sure when is it suppose to be displayed.